Controlling white space inside box()
I'm working with bs4dash to create a Shiny-app. However, I'm unable to alter the white space in the box() itself. There's always quite some space between the gray line of the headerBorder and the table. I would like to be be able to play with the excess white space, so the table is as close to the headerBorder as possible.
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  title = "Example",
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        "Page 1",
        tabName = "example_page",
        icon = icon("e")
      )
  )),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "example_page",
        fluidRow(
          sortable(
            width = 7,
            box(title = "Example box",
                headerBorder = T,
                gt_output("gt_example"),
                width = 12,
                height = 200)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$gt_example <- render_gt({
    mpg |> head(2) |> gt()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)



Set padding-top of the .card-body and the children of your table (#gt_example > div) to 0px:

library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  title = "Example",
  header = dashboardHeader(
    title = "Example",
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
     ".card-body, #gt_example > div {
        padding-top: 0px !important;
      }")))),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        "Page 1",
        tabName = "example_page",
        icon = icon("e")
      )
    )),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "example_page",
        fluidRow(
          sortable(
            width = 7,
            box(title = "Example box",
                headerBorder = T,
                gt_output("gt_example"),
                width = 12,
                height = 200)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$gt_example <- render_gt({
    mpg |> head(2) |> gt()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


In my actual Shiny app I had to put it in my dashboardBody() instead of the dashboardHeader() for it to work, but it got the job done. Thanks for the help!
